# The variable 'buff' is being used without being defined

Tags: c, arrays, text, runtime

I need to read some data from text file and store it in 2D-array.
This code works good:

```
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("Read.txt", "r");
    char buff[100][100];
    char str[100];
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(str, 100, f)) {
        strcpy(buff[i], str);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But why doesn't it work when I try to change buff definition in line 5 to:

```
char (*buff)[100];
```

I expected this definition to work too.
The error I get:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'buff' is being used without being defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char (*buff)[100];
```

Here `buff` is a pointer to an array of 100 characters. So first you should make the pointer point to valid memory location before storing some value in it.

Presuming you want to go for dynamic memory allocation then you can have

```
char *buff[100];
```

Now in the `fgets()` loop allocate memory to each pointer individually like

```
buff[i] = malloc(100);
```

Note here buff is an array of 100 char pointers.

Comment: Ok, could you tell how to make this pointer to point to valid location?

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik I don't see a need for a pointer here. What are you trying to achieve by using this pointer?

Comment: it just for practice. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik I hope you got the difference between them and what to use when